# Is a recursive function in a ternary operator evaluated twice?

Tags: c++, recursion

I came across an article that has the following statement:

```cpp
maxSubArray(A, i) = maxSubArray(A, i - 1) > 0 ? maxSubArray(A, i - 1) : 0 + A[i];
```

My question is, would `maxSubArray(A, i - 1)` be evaluated (called) twice (if its value is greater than 0)?  Does it increase the time complexity of the code?  I think so, since we would end up calling the recursive function twice (if its value is greater than 0).

Edit: Here's the code:

```cpp
public int maxSubArray(int[] A) {
        int n = A.length;
        int[] dp = new int[n];//dp[i] means the maximum subarray ending with A[i];
        dp[0] = A[0];
        int max = dp[0];
        
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            dp[i] = A[i] + (dp[i - 1] > 0 ? dp[i - 1] : 0);
            max = Math.max(max, dp[i]);
        }
        
        return max;
}
```

and here is the [related link](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/discuss/20193/DP-solution-and-some-thoughts).  The above code is not directly related, since the one in my original question is from top-down DP approach, while the one added later on is from a bottom-up DP approach.

Comment: why would it not be called twice? complexity in terms of what? Doing something twice just adds a constant factor which doesnt count for big-O complexity

Comment: Well, I meant the time complexity.  I think it would increase because we can end up calling the recursive function twice (if the value >0).

Comment: I have the feeling that this is just a way of denoting the recurrence relation between `maxSubArray(A,i)` and `maxSubArray(A,i-1)` but not actually meant to be real code. Some context would be good

Comment: Yes, it is just a way of denoting the recurrence relation between `maxSubArray(A,i)` and `maxSubArray(A,i-1)`.  I know an easy way to avoid it would be to store the value of `maxSubArray(A, i-1)` in a variable beforehand; but I am curious about what is going on in the way it is written above (is the time complexity increased).

Comment: to know what is going on in that line we need to know what `maxSubArray` is. It appears on the lhs, so it must return something assignable, but then it also appears on the rhs, which confuses me because either it returns a reference and you want to store the result of some computation in there, or it returns the result of some computation, but how can it be both? Is this called in a loop to fill some sort of array with the results?

Comment: complexity does not increase when you do something twice. There seems to be some recursion, but how exactly is not clear

Comment: I have added the code and the associated link.  "complexity does not increase when you do something twice." - true and I agree, but in this case that something is recursion, which is why I am confused.

Comment: in the code you posted the function only takes a single argument

Comment: Yes, because like I mentioned in the edit, it is bottom-up approach; but my question is from top-down.

Comment: as I guessed, this is not meant to be code. It is just to express the relation between some `A_[i]` and `A_[i-1]`. As it isnt code and the presented implementation is something different it doesnt make much sense to ponder about its complexity. Its like writing `y = 5 * x` vs `int mult(int x) { return x*5; }`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, ok, that makes sense.  Thank you! :)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: calling recursive functions twice might change the complexity: `int f(int n) { if (n == 0) return 1; return 2 * f(n - 1); }` versus `int f(int n) { if (n == 0) return 1; return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1); }` linear versus exponentiel.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah I know, I tried to be careful with statements above, maybe not careful enough ;). A definition of `maxSubArray` was needed to know what is the impact on complexity. Turned out that there is none it is just pseudo code. Or rather it appears as `dp[i] = A[i] + (dp[i - 1] > 0 ? dp[i - 1] : 0);` in the implementation where `dp[i -1]` is just accessing an element in an array, ie no impact on complexity

Comment: well thats sounds like it could be an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> ```
> maxSubArray(A, i) = maxSubArray(A, i - 1) > 0 ? maxSubArray(A, i - 1) : 0 + A[i];
> ```

is just a pseudo code notation of the relation between `maxSubArray(A, i - 1)` and `maxSubArray(A, i)`. It just tells us how to compute the result for `i` when we do know the result for `i-1`. Read it like maths notation. Similar as

```
y = 5 * x
```

describes

```
int foo(int x) { return x*5; }
```

In the actual implementation the above recurrence relation is realized via:

> ```
> dp[i] = A[i] + (dp[i - 1] > 0 ? dp[i - 1] : 0);
> ```

Here `dp[i - 1]` is merely accessing an element of an array. Accessing the same array element twice has no impact on complexity. Given that `dp[i-1]` is not modified in that line, a compiler might optimize it to access `dp[i-1]` only once.

---

In the presence of recursion, unnecessarily calling a function twice can have an impact on complexity. Consider this example (stolen from Jarod42):

```
int f(int n) { 
    if (n == 0) return 1; 
    return 2 * f(n - 1); 
} 

int f(int n) { 
    if (n == 0) return 1; 
    return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1);
}
```

Both yield the same result, but the first has linear complexity while the second is exponential.